# Toolbox shows up when changing tabs in an userform

Tags: excel

I've encountered a strange issue. I have an Microsoft Excel file, which opens an userform upon starting. When I click on some some tabs (multipage) Excel shows me toolbox (to add or remove items in the form).

The problem is that this toolbox shows not in VBA editor, but on a running file (although after clicking tabs back and forth it disappears). How I can prevent toolbox showing when the form is running? Maybe some multipage properties are doing this?

Comment: By multipage you mean multiple sheets?

Comment: No, multipage, as in panel with tabs in an userform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a similar problem.

I found out that if a frame or multipage is enabled but the content in those fields are disabled (ie a button) then the toolbox will show up when tabbing through. You need to have a least one content in that field enabled.

I had to make my VBA code disable the frame when certain criteria was not met. This stopped the toolbox from showing up when tabbing.

When I say enable and disable I mean the property .enable = TRUE or FALSE.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As described in another [thread](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/942540-vbe-toolbox-keeps-popping-up-when-running-userforms.html) by [torachan](https://www.excelforum.com/members/464474.html) it seems, vba stores the visibility of the toolbar for some form-object types, such as frames and multipages. Whenever some properties of one of these objects change, the toolbox pops up, if the window/object was stored with the toolbox visible.

Therefore, the solution is to **open the user-form in VBE** and show the toolbox manually and close it again. This has to be done for all form-items not only for the window itself. **Then save the forms workbook with the toolbox invisible for the window and all sub-items.**